# Returning nested arrays from multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following 2x2 array:

```
var aTest = [
    ['test00','test01'],
    ['test10','test11']
]
```

I can return all of the nested arrays from the first (zero-eth), parent array. i.e.: aTest[0] returns

```
['test00', 'test01']
```

However, I can't do the same thing for the nested array without looping. i.e. I would like to do: aTest[][0]:

```
[['test00'],['test10']]
```

Am I mistaken? Is there no way to achieve this without loops:

```
var aTemp = new Array();
for ( var i = 0; i < aTest.length; i++ ) {
    aTemp[i] = new Array();
    aTemp[i][0] = aTest[i][0];
};
```

Comment: So... You want to return columns? Those are not nested arrays in your second example, so you will need to iterate through.

Comment: You can simplify the loop body to `aTemp[i] = [aTest[i][0]];`. Also, this will be pretty short with ES6: `var aTemp = aTest.map(x => [x[0]]);`.

Comment: @FelixKling those are good shortcuts. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you have to iterate through each element of your array to achieve this.

You can optimize the code using [`map()` function of Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
var aTest = [
    ['test00','test01'],
    ['test10','test11']
]

var firstItems = aTest.map(function(item){
   return item[0];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Dang, I was hoping to achieve this without looping of some sort. Oh well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Bigood's answer (which is where my mind went), you can create a generalized "col" function that returns a column from a multi-dimensional array (note: JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays in the mathematical sense of the word; it simply has arrays that can contain other arrays).

```
function col(a, n) { return a.map(function(x) { return x[n]; }); }
```

If you want to be really spiffy, you can add it to `Array.prototype` (Note: some people feel very strongly that you shouldn't modify built-in types.  I'm not one of them.):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'col', {
    value: function(n) {
        return this.map(function(x) { return x[n]; });
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
aTest.col(0)    // ['test00', 'test10']
aTest.col(1)    // ['test01', 'test11']
```

Comment: Thanks for the complement, I was lazy to go that far ;)